# Isomorphism problem involving the Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

> Let $G$ be a group of order $24$ with no elements of order $6$. Prove that $G$ isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$.

This is what I did and I'm a bit unease about it since I didn't use that G has no element of order 6.

Let A = {1,2,3,4}. Suppose that G is acting on A by left multiplication.

Then $\phi$ : $G \longrightarrow S_A$ is a Homorphism.

By the First Isomorphism Theorem:

$ | \ker \phi| | |G| =S_A =S_4 $

But this says that $ \ker \phi = 1$ and thus $\phi$ is injective. This establishes that G is isomorphic to $ S_4$

Comment: You haven't defined $\phi$, you've just asserted it exists and that it is a homomorphism.

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: $\phi: a \longrightarrow g*a$

Comment: What is $ga$ supposed to be? I understand that you meant that $\phi(g)$ is the map $a\mapsto ga$, but this has no sense.

Comment: @andraiamatrix: he defines it as left multiplication, as in the cae where $G$ acts on itself. It simply doesn't work here.

Comment: @Antoine Maybe i just translated the notation wrong from my book. However, my book says that The map G to $ S_A$ defined by g $\longrightarrow \sigma_g$ is a Homomorphism.

Comment: @Scripture: indeed, but $\sigma_g$ *can't be defined this way*. See William Ballinger's answer to see why this can't work. Please note that elements of $G$ are completely abstract, and unless you give a meaning to $g*a$, your action isn't defined.

Comment: There is an additional problem: this proof also assumes that the  map $G\to S_4$ is surjective, otherwise the First Isomorphism Theorem cannot be applied in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem need Sylow theorem and group actions:

Since $G$ has no element of order 6, $G$ can not have only one Sylow $3$-subgroup. (If $n_3=1$, then $N_G(P)=G$. Note $G/C_G(P)\le Aut(P)\cong\{±1\}$. Therefore $2\mid|C_G(P)|$, and then there exists element of order 6 in $C_G(P)$, a contradiction.) By Sylow theorem, $G$ has exactly 4 Sylow $3$-sugroups. Let $P$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup, $K=N_G(P)$, then $|G:K|=4$. Thus $G$ acts on the 4 cosets of $K$ in $G$, which implies $G/K_G$ is a subgroup of $S_4$, where $K_G=\cap_{g\in G} K^g$. If $|K_G|=2$, then $K_G\le Z(G)$ and we will find an element of order 6. If $|K_G|=3$, then $K_G=P$, then $K=G$, a contradiction. Hence $|K_G|=1$, and $G \cong S_4$.

Comment: @YACP Action by conjugation gives a map $S_4\to \operatorname{Aut}(P)\cong\{\pm\}$.  The kernel has order 12 or 24, and in particular contains an element of order $2$.

Comment: Can someone please explain why $n_3=4$ and not 1 ?

Comment: If $n_3=1$, then $N_G(P)=G$. Note $G/C_G(P) \le Aut(P)\cong {\pm 1}$. Therefore $2||C_G(P)|$, and there exists element of order 6 in C_G(P)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Comment included in the answer (where it has to be!). Btw, I'm not so sure that you find an element of order 6 in $C_G(P)$, but certainly find one in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your proof is that there will not necessarily be an action of $G$ on $A$.

For example, if $G$ had an element of order $6$, then it couldn't act on $A$ because any bijection $A\mapsto A$ has order at most $4$.

To fix your proof, you just need to show that any group of order $24$ with no element of order $6$ acts on $\{1,2,3,4\}$.